# Java Preparedstatement error when reading from MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a simple application that pulls data from a local database. The below code works fine when I use a string for the SQL query, but I can not get it to work with PreparedStatement. I have reviewed similar problems posted here but most of those were caused by doing this, preparedStmt.executeQuery(query); instead of this preparedStmt.executeQuery(); Here is the code,

```
    private final String POSTTITLE=     "posttitle"; // DB Column name
    private final String POSTCONTENT=   "content"; // DB Column name

   public String getDbContent(){
        try{
            String query ="select values(?, ?) from blog";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = this.connect.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString (1,POSTTITLE);
            preparedStmt.setString (2,POSTCONTENT);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            return(rs.getString(this.POSTCONTENT)); //Will replace with loop to get all content
        } catch(Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Error Reading database!");
           System.err.println(e);
           return("Error: "+e);
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''posttitle', 'content') from blog' at line 1

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to have the column names separated from the query? The syntax for `SELECT` is never `SELECT VALUES() FROM ...` but rather `SELECT expression1, expression2, ... FROM ...` with the expressions involving column names. In most cases, you know the columns you want to get in advance. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with this query.

Comment: Yes I think you're right, there is no real reason to programmatically input the columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters in prepared statements are for values - you're trying to use them to select fields. They just don't work that way.

In this *very specific* instance, you'll need to make the SQL dynamic. However, you'll want to make sure that whatever code you have to allow your columns to be specified is tightly constrained to avoid SQL injection attacks. (For example, you could have an enum with the columns in, or a whitelist of allowed values.)

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating select query:

```
String query ="select "+POSTTITLE+","+POSTCONTENT+" from blog";
```

Remember that prepared statements are for values, not query parameters, for them we use simply concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String query ="select POSTTITLE, POSTCONTENT from blog";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = this.connect.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
```

There is no need to use field names as parameter.